# How can an Accelo Web Application determine the 'staff ID' of the logged-in user?

Tags: api, oauth, documentation

Using [the 'Web Application' OAuth flow](https://affinitylive.jira.com/wiki/display/APIS/Web+Applications) of the Accelo API, where can the 'staff ID' of the logged-in user be found?

The staff ID is used in other requests, such as [Activities.](https://affinitylive.jira.com/wiki/display/APIS/Activities)

It doesn't appear to be returned as part of the OAuth callback.

Nor do [the `/tokeninfo`](https://affinitylive.jira.com/wiki/display/APIS/Token+Info) [and `/user`](https://affinitylive.jira.com/wiki/display/APIS/User) endpoints mention it.

There's not even some kind of "whoami" method among [the `/staff` endpoints.](https://affinitylive.jira.com/wiki/display/APIS/Staff)

---

(For the moment, I'm relying on the user to have at least one [Timer](https://affinitylive.jira.com/wiki/display/APIS/List+Timers) started. The `/timers?_fields=staff` endpoint returns only the current user's Timers, and shows the staff ID for each.)

(Also, the application will not be granted `write` permissions in the scope, so creating a dummy Timer is not possible.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [the quick work of the people at Accelo,](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/accelo-devs/F9Bu42NbaD8/qelvbAg6BgAJ) the staff ID is now available in several endpoints:

## `/staff/whoami`

Sample response:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "message": "Everything executed as expected.",
    "more_info": "https://affinitylive.jira.com/wiki/display/APIS/Status+Codes#ok",
    "status": "ok"
  },
  "response": {
    "firstname": "Robert",
    "id": "23",
    "surname": "Bell"
  }
}
```

## `/tokeninfo`

Sample response:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "message": "Everything executed as expected.",
    "more_info": "https://affinitylive.jira.com/wiki/display/APIS/Status+Codes#ok",
    "status": "ok"
  },
  "response": {
    "deployment": "example",
    "email": "Robert@example.com",
    "expiry_date": "1412345678",
    "firstname": "Robert",
    "locale": {
      "currency": {
        "symbol": "$"
      },
      "timezone": "Australia/Sydney"
    },
    "staff_id": "23",
    "surname": "Bell"
  }
}
```

## `/user`

Sample response:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "message": "Everything executed as expected.",
    "more_info": "https://affinitylive.jira.com/wiki/display/APIS/Status+Codes#ok",
    "status": "ok"
  },
  "response": {
    "email": "Robert@example.com",
    "fax": "",
    "financial_level": "all",
    "firstname": "Robert",
    "id": "23",
    "locale": {
      "currency": {
        "symbol": "$"
      },
      "timezone": "Australia/Sydney"
    },
    "mobile": "+61234567890",
    "phone": "09 1234 5678",
    "position": "Developer",
    "surname": "Bell",
    "timezone": "Australia/Sydney",
    "title": null,
    "user_access": {
      "account_invoice": {
        "add": 1,
        "admin": 1,
        "dashboard": "",
        "manages": 0,
        "view": 1
      },
      "activity": {
        "add": 1,
        "admin": 1,
        "dashboard": 1,
        "manages": 0,
        "view": 1
      },
      // ...
    },
    "user_titles": {
      "account_invoice": {
        "plural": "Invoices",
        "singular": "Invoice"
      },
      "account_purchase": {
        "plural": "Purchases",
        "singular": "Purchase"
      },
      // ...
    },
    "username": "robert@example.com"
  }
}
```